# How to scroll ViewPager both horizontally and vertically in Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview, viewpagerindicator

I have a ViewPager whose contents are determined runtime. The content size might be more than the screen dimensions, so I thought of having the ViewPager inside a NestedScrollView (which enables vertical scroll) which is inside a HorizontalScrollView (which enables horizontal scroll). This solves the problem of fitting the content, but I am unable to scroll through the ViewPager tabs - possibly ViewPager is not receiving the horizontal scrolls anymore.

For example, in a scenario when content width is more than screen width, my initial scroll should first scroll to the end of content's edges - and then the new content from the FragmentAdapter should be loaded. But with nested scrollview approach, I am unable to load next item from the FragmentAdapter.

My code :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

There is one alternative to this approach. Drop the outer HorizontalScrollView and put the content of ViewPager's FragmentAdapter in a HorizontalScrollView. I am yet to try this solution - but this would lead me to change and retest all my existing layout files for the FragmentAdapter.

Comment: Use ViewPager for horizontal scroll. And use RecyclerView for implementing vertical scroll inside the viewpager contents.

Comment: What if the viewpage content's width and height are more than screen size ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use bellow references. Good Implementation.

[DoubleViewPager](https://github.com/juliome10/DoubleViewPager)